Magento 2.4.7 UPS shipping method not working
i have configured UPS shipping method in magento 2.4.7, my credentials are proper and still i am unable to view shipping method. verify below images.
UPS configurations :
1 : https://i.sstatic.net/fJ2VoX6t.png
2 : https://i.sstatic.net/YjInPG9x.png
3 : https://i.sstatic.net/2UrRmBM6.png
shipping origin :
4: https://i.sstatic.net/Jfz0TEf2.png
frontend output :
5: https://i.sstatic.net/J3SS7Q2C.png
